# Why is pipenv referring to a local library and not the library which is in the virtual env?

Tags: python, pip, pytest, pipenv

Here are my pipenv details

```
❯ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2020.11.15
```

I am creating the env with the following command:

```
❯ pipenv shell    
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /Users/myname/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-q3ssQWxH/bin/activate
/Users/myname/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: line 162: exec: python3.8: not found                                     

❯  . /Users/myname/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-q3ssQWxH/bin/activate
```

Now if I do `which python`, it points me to the correct python i.e., the one which is in the virtual environment. But when I do which `pytest` it points me to system pytest and not the one which is installed in virtual env:

```
❯ which python
/Users/myname/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-q3ssQWxH/bin/python

❯ which pytest
/usr/local/bin/pytest
```

How can I fix this so that pytest refers to the virtual env library?

Comment: `pipenv install pytest `?

Comment: It doesn't appear that `pytest` *is* installed in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain how it normally works first.

When creating a virtual environment with pipenv, not only does it provide you an isolated `site-packages` folder, it also provides an isolated `bin` folder, for Python packages that come with executables/CLI (like pytest). If you `pipenv install` a package, its executables/CLI will also be installed into that virtual env's `bin` as well.

```
(demo) demo$ pipenv --venv
/Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/demo-tSf-ZA7f

(demo) demo$ ls /Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/demo-tSf-ZA7f
bin        lib        pyvenv.cfg

(demo) demo$ pipenv install pytest
Installing pytest...
⠋ Installing pytest...
...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (a834da)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a834da)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00

(demo) demo$ which pytest
/Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/demo-tSf-ZA7f/bin/pytest
```

However, pipenv does not block or hide the system-wide `bin` folders. What it actually does is prepend the virtual env's `bin` into the system `PATH` so that when the OS is looking for some executable/CLI, the virtual env `bin` files are checked first, before the system-wide `bin` files.

```
(demo) demo$ echo $PATH
/Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/demo-tSf-ZA7f/bin:/usr/local/bin:/other/paths
```

Notice that `PATH` has the path to the currently activated virtual env first. So, `which pytest` and pytest will find and resolve to the virtual env's copy first. Also note that `/usr/local/bin` is *still* also on the `PATH`, but it's *after* the virtual env's `bin`.

That's how it should work normally. In your case, you already have pytest installed using your system-wide Python (as indicated by `/usr/local/bin/pytest`), so it can be found on your `PATH`, *even when inside a Pipenv virtual environment*.

One of the following things happened:

#### 1) You have not installed pytest yet in your virtual environment

```
demo$ which pytest
/usr/local/bin/pytest

demo$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/demo-tSf-ZA7f/bin/activate
demo$  . /Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/demo-tSf-ZA7f/bin/activate

(demo) demo$ which pytest
/Users/gino.mempin/.venvs/demo-tSf-ZA7f/bin/pytest

(demo) demo$ pipenv uninstall pytest
Uninstalling pytest...
Found existing installation: pytest 6.2.1
Uninstalling pytest-6.2.1:
  Successfully uninstalled pytest-6.2.1
...

(demo) demo$ which pytest
/usr/local/bin/pytest
```

When pytest was uninstalled, OS could not find it anymore from the virtual env `bin`, so it started looking for it in the rest of the `PATH` folders, ending up with the system-wide installation on `/usr/local/bin`.

So, make sure that you *really* have pytest installed.

#### 2) You made modifications to pipenv's activation script

Somewhere in the virtual env's activation script is where it prepends the virtual env's `bin` to the `PATH`:

```
(demo) demo$ cat $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
...
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
...
```

Tampering with `PATH` could lead to your OS looking into `/usr/local/bin` first before the virtual environment's `bin`. In that case, even if you installed pytest in your virtual env, it would still resolve pytest to the system-wide one.

So, make sure to check what `echo $PATH` prints out while you are inside the virtual environment.